# Warning when opening html file from folder

Tags: html, excel, vba

I have a  Macro that will open a HTML website from a folder saved on my computer.  However I get a notification that looks like this and then it wont continue with my macro.  I tried disabling the notification but that doesnt work.  Is there a code that I can put in my excel VBA to bypass this error or to not prompt it at all.

[image]

Comment: That's not an "error", that is the system protecting itself from harm. You cannot bypass a user's security.

Comment: You could try asking on SuperUser, maybe there is an option in their settings they can use to suppress the pop-up. It would likely be user-by-user and not have an in-script solution.